# Mongoid eager-loading(`includes`) behavior when identity_map is turned off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am trying to understand the eager-loading(`includes`) behavior when identity_map is turned off.

```
class Account
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscriptions
end

a = Account.includes(:subscriptions).first # makes first two calls to the database
a.subscriptions # returns nothing
a.subscriptions.map(&:name) # makes the 3rd call to the database.
```

As per the documentation `includes` selector is supposed to work only when the identity_map is enabled.
But in my case the Mongoid library tries to eager load included associations even when identity_map is disabled. This results in a redundant call to the database when the association is accessed later.

```
MOPED: yyyy:10019 QUERY database=xxxx collection=accounts 
  selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} 
  flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (148.0079ms)

MOPED: yyyy:10019 QUERY database=xxxx collection=subscriptions 
  selector={"_id"=>{"$in"=>["50eaad6b6f758a601a000017", "50eaad7e6f758a601a000036"]}} 
  flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (573.0329ms)

MOPED: yyyy:10019 QUERY database=xxxx collection=subscriptions 
  selector={"$and"=>[{"_id"=>{"$in"=>["50eaad6b6f758a601a000017", 
  "50eaad7e6f758a601a000036"]}}]} 
  flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (586.0329ms)
```